# Location of WebRTC Ice Servers

Tags: webrtc

I currently have 2 ice servers -- STUN (from Google) and one TURN server (in the US).

If I add more ice servers (to the ice servers array passed to the peer connection) from different locations (IE Europe, Asia, South America etc.), will WebRTC be smart enough about using the optimal TURN servers between users who connect with each other (if TURN is needed between them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory ICE will take care of this.

However, this will keep open a NAT binding to each TURN server which is rather wasteful. Using geodns like Amazons route53 to let clients create an allocation on the TURN server that is closest is usually better.

Comment: From my understanding, being connected to the server closer to you doesn't necessarily mean that it's the best server to use for you and your partner. A server in between you and your partner would be more optimal, so I think that server would still need to be passed in the ice servers configuration? Or should there be logics to remove / add optimal ice servers on the fly as connections are made between peers?

Comment: It will be the best server for you while your partner will have their own best server. If in addition the connection between the servers is better than the connection between your optimal server and your partner
This would result in a relay-relay candidate pair instead of a relay-srflx or relay-prflx pair. I have seen both, don't have actual numbers on the proportions however.

I do not expect (gut feeling) the difference in RTT between server "in the middle" and two servers close to the clients to be larger than some ten milliseconds, at the cost of greater deployment complexity.

Comment: changing servers during the call is not possible due to the lack of setConfiguration (formerly known as updateIce). Also [nombis](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-uberti-mmusic-nombis-00) is not implemented yet which means that the selection of candidate pairs is not very dynamic.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think 1 STUN server and 2 TURN servers (US, Europe) be more efficient by a good margin than just 1 TURN in US? (users being from all around the world). Just wondering if the improvement is worth setting up another EU server.

Comment: Same question for using Amazons route53 to handle which TURN server gets assigned -- improvement worth the time spent setting it up?

Comment: It is typically worth it. I had this blog post in the queue which discusses that: https://medium.com/@fippo/where-to-deploy-turn-or-other-relay-servers-2dab2e8157ea

Comment: Let's say an American connects to a North American server, and a guy from China, from an Asian server. I'm not sure how they will be able to connect via TURN (or even STUN), if they don't have at least one server in common in their PC configurations?